# Combining three SQL queries into one to find a data with reference to a given table order

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand I couldn't come up with the right title for this question.  Perhaps I will edit it after some inputs from community members.

I have `TableA`, `TableB`, `TableC`.   For simplicity reasons,  assume they all have `ProductID` and `Price` as fields.

In the code,  first `TableA` is searched. If it contains the price for the productid,  return.  If not,  search `TableB` for the same and then `TableC` for the same.  In many cases, it results in three separate queries.   SQL experts is there a way to run just one query with a hierarchical preference.  Meaning if the price is found in `TableA` disregard the results from the remaining two tables,  then the second option is to accept the price from `TableB` if the price doesn't exist in `TableA`.  Meaning,  if all three table contains the price,  take the price from `TableA`.  If the price doesn't exist in `TableA` take it from `TableB` and finally from `TableC` that will always has the price.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @AllenKing: if you find someone else's comments rude or abusive, then the best thing to do is to flag them to the moderators for their review and removal (if necessary). Otherwise, there's not much that you can do to prevent anyone, myself included, from commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this uses filtering:

```
select a.productid, a.price, 'a' as which
from a
union all
select b.productid, b.price, 'b' as which
from b
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.productid = b.productid)
union all
select c.productid, c.price, 'c' as which
from c
where not exists (select 1 from a where a.productid = c.productid) and
      not exists (select 1 from b where b.productid = c.productid) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use below query. You need to provide specific ProductID in the @SearchProductID variable.Like now I use @SearchProductID :=1.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT IF(A.ProductID =  @SearchProductID && @price<1 , @price := A.Price, IF(B.ProductID = @SearchProductID && @price<1, @price := B.Price, IF(C.ProductID = @SearchProductID && @price<1, @price := C.Price,@price=0 ))) AS Rprice FROM 
TableA A ,TableB B,TableC C , (SELECT @price :=0 , @SearchProductID :=1) C) R
WHERE R.Rprice>0
```

Comment: This kind of variable assignment is meaningless without an ORDER BY clause.